# What is the Recovery Point Objective (RPO) of a single RDS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I know there are automatic snapshots created every 24 hours, and that you can recover point in time in a minute timeframe. But what is the Recovery Point Objective (RPO)? Is this a minute? Or 24 hours because you need the latest daily snapshot? The documentation is not clear about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RPO Should be 5 mins https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIT.html

> RDS uploads transaction logs for DB instances to Amazon S3 every 5 minutes. To determine the latest restorable time for a DB instance, use the AWS CLI describe-db-instances command and look at the value returned in the LatestRestorableTime field for the DB instance. In the AWS Management Console, this property is visible as the Latest restore time for the DB instance. You can restore to any point in time during your backup retention period.

Someone tested it back in 2012 with a powershell script. https://www.yobyot.com/aws/aws-rds-backup-recovery/2016/02/09/

> As you can see in the screenshot below, a simple PowerShell script that ran for 20 minutes demonstrates that AWS is, indeed, making that very tight RPO possible. My little test instance was off only twice, by an insignificant minute or so.

Archived Link: http://archive.vn/8ZbuS https://web.archive.org/web/20190102131221/https://www.yobyot.com/aws/aws-rds-backup-recovery/2016/02/09/